# how to remove image stuck in my nib after all references removed

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

My iPad app will periodically crash with a memory warning, and it shows "Could not load the "myimage.png" image referenced from a nib in bundle..."

I have removed this from my .h and the nib and it, obviously is not in my bundle.  I cannot get rid of this reference.  I have checked everything there is no pointer to it in my nib or in my code, how can I view my nib such that I can get rid of this bad reference??

Anyone else experience this?

Comment: I should also add that I cleaned all targets and emptied xcode caches

Comment: Also you can open the xib as xml and search for references just to be sure. That should give a hint as to any properties that may still have it set if a build clean did not work.

Comment: what is the stack trace when the program crash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never seen that happen but you could just open the .xib file in a text/xml editor and do a search for myimage.png. CHeck that out and infer the problem from what you find :) Post what you find if you cannot get a solution from that.

Comment: great idea!!  Why didn't I think of that. I opened the nib in Dashcode and expected to find it, but to my disappointment  it wasn't there!!?..  In the past I had even tried putting the image back in my bundle, but I still go the error.. weird

Comment: it was referenced as a background image in a custom button that I set to .02 alpha so it is touchable but hidden from view.. .  I don't recall putting the image in there but there it was!  opening the nib showed it as a uibutton, which lead me to check my buttons.

thanks!